# Python: How to reshape a multidimensional array with various dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Suppose I have an array like this

[[1,2], [3,4,5]]

and I would like to reshape it to

[[[1],[2]], [[3],[4],[5]]]

Is there a simple way to do so in Python? I know this is super easy if the 2nd dimension is the same across the entire data, but in my case the length of my 2nd dimension is 2 and 3, respectively.

Many Thanks.

Comment: numpy doesn't support ragged arrays like that.  are you sure you don't have a list of lists?

Comment: Well, this request is in fact coming from image classification.

Comment: Sorry I didn't finish yesterday. So when I read image of RGB color into python, it only comes with format like [[1,2], [3,4,5]], however to use keras CNN, the last dimension has to be an array, like [[[1],[2]], [[3],[4],[5]]]. The answers are great if the number of images are relatively small, but when there are 100,000 images of various sizes it could take a while to finish

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list like that:

```
nested = [[1,2], [3,4,5]]
```

you could split it out like so:

```
nested_split = [[[single_elt] for single_elt in inside_list] for inside_list in nested]
```

which would give you the following output when calling print:

```
[[[1], [2]], [[3], [4], [5]]]
```

The dimensionality of the inner or outer lists doesn't affect this solution in any way, since the use of the for loops and list comprehension will dynamically accommodate any size list.

Answer (score 0):

We can quibble about whether this is a list of lists or multidimensional array, but `concateante` does a nice job of flattening it into a 1d array:

```
In [173]: alist = [[1,2], [3,4,5]]
In [175]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)
Out[175]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Then it's easy to reshape it into a (5,1) shape array:

```
In [176]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=0).reshape(-1,1)
Out[176]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

There are idioms for flattening a list of lists, but since you flagged this a numpy, the numpy approach is more obvious.

```
In [177]: import itertools
In [178]: list(itertools.chain(*alist))
Out[178]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [180]: [[x] for x in itertools.chain(*alist)]
Out[180]: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `x for x in array` mechanism:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4,5]]
>>> [[[a2] for a2 in a1] for a1 in a]
[[[1], [2]], [[3], [4], [5]]]
```